# How to fix Redirect 301 problem with multiple subdirectory

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

I have many redirection with my .htaccess.
Some of my url works fine but others not working.

Many of my url are broken and give this result :

I try this :

```
Redirect 301 https://mywebsite.com/old-directory/old-directory/old-content  https://mywebsite.com/new-directory/new-directory/new-content
```

And the url give me a 404 error with this url : https://mywebsite.com/new-directory/new-directory/old-content

it's like the redirection is not finished.